# Conditional execution based on database load (Oracle database)

Tags: java, database, oracle

We have a situation where we have to perform a lengthy query to the database based on human input. As the input changes, the query has to be done over and over again, and the input may change once per second.

The problem is, we know that this will cause a spike in server activity for several seconds, and since it is not critical to have an answer immediately or on every input change, it means we can afford executing or not executing the query.

The criteria we would like to use is the current state of the database server, and only allow the query to be done if it is in a low or medium load state, skipping the query when the database server is under stress.

We use Oracle database for this, and so far we have not found any way, from Java, to do this except by actually loading into the server a known query and benchmark it, but that is essentially adding some load to the server. So my question: is there any other way, specifically in Oracle database, where we can discover from the Java side of the application the load of the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you define "low or medium load state", I'd guess that hitting [`v$osstat`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2010.htm#REFRN30321) would give you the information you're after   Of course, hitting `v$osstat` constantly will also add to the load on the server.  You may want to write a job that copies the `v$osstat` data to a table you control periodically (and can thus index appropriately) so that your application can hit that table rather than hitting the dynamic performance view constantly.  Depending on the goal (i.e. are you trying to ensure that other users have enough resources or are you trying to ensure that your app remains responsive), you may want to use Resource Manager to control resource utilization among users, you may want to run the query asynchronously from the application, and/or you may want to use some sort of cache at the middle tier to avoid hitting the database every time.

Comment: This is the type of thing I was looking for. Thank you very much.